# Fetch credit card saved in Safari and show in IOS app

Tags: ios, swift, credit-card

I am trying to fetch credit cards saved in Safari autofill, to the IOS app. My moto is to show the list of card saved in the app and user should be able to pick any. I am new to IOS app development looking for any help around this

I have not tried anything yet, I was searching for the initial knowledge to get started with. There are some blocks which talks about credit card autofill on websites surfed on Safari. Want to implement same experience in app.

Comment: I doubt that this is possible for privacy and security reasons.